# using shortcodes in theme content

Tags: shortcode

I am using plugin like to read http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/like-to-keep-reading/
problem is its using opening and closing shortcodes,when I embed them to my site http://vijaykudal.info only opening short codes displayed,can you please help me?
PS:-tried with different themes as well

Comment: By opening and closing shortcodes, do you mean [shortcode]something[/shortcode] ?

Comment: Can you point us to an example post that you are trying to put it in?

Comment: any post in blog is same since I added code in theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put shortcode within a PHP template, use [do_shortcode();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode( '[like_to_read]The text that is hidden from the user.[/like_to_read]' );
?>
```

Edit:

```
 <?php
    echo do_shortcode( '[like_to_read]' . get_the_content() . '[/like_to_read]' );
    ?>
```

Comment: thats also not worked

Comment: Are you using the shortcode within page.php? You need to give some more information here. Is it within the page content in TinyMCE Editor?

Comment: in theme,mainly single.php

Comment: one more thing,I want to hind whole content block

Comment: Added what the shortcode would look like. Please ensure that you do have the plugin set up properly, and that you can get the shortcode to work within TinyMCE before you try within the template .php files. Does it work when in TinyMCE?

Comment: With tinymcs working,but with theme it does not,plz have a look at sample post http://marathi.vijaykudal.info/%e0%a4%95%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%80-%e0%a4%b5%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%9a%e0%a4%a3%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%af%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%96%e0%a5%87-%e0%a4%9c%e0%a4%b0%e0%a5%82%e0%a4%b0-%e0%a4%b5.html

Comment: hey ,worked fine when i changed theme

Comment: As posted below, your theme must have deactivated shortcodes. So is it working now? If so, please mark this solved. :) Happy WPing!

Answer (score 0):

my your theme deactived shortcodes , so 
this tools save time to search about shortcode remove word in folders
so when tool got installed, click on theme file and click on grepwin then write  remove_shortcode then wait to see the resluts , and after if there's any pages contains  remove_shortcode will appear in box bellow, all u had to do is playing with codes may it works ! or simply you can user this shortcode

for example

```
function shortcode_content_post_url() {

    echo 'short codes is cool';
     }
add_shortcode('cool', 'shortcode_content_post_url');
```

and in url post type `[cool]`

then it will appear short codes is cool